# What is the gain of a unit test like this?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit

**A test case that I can't understand usefulness** (taken from [Plaid](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/main/designernews/src/test/java/io/plaidapp/designernews/data/users/UserRemoteDataSourceTest.kt)):

What is the point here? With this line, you're already telling your framework to return a predefined result whenever `getUsers()` method is called and then you verify that it actually returns a predefined result.
`whenever(service.getUsers("111,222")).thenReturn(Response.success(users))`

```
@Test
fun getUsers_withSuccess() = runBlocking {
    // Given that the service responds with success
    whenever(service.getUsers("111,222")).thenReturn(Response.success(users))

    // When requesting the users
    val result = dataSource.getUsers(listOf(111L, 222L))

    // Then there's one request to the service
    verify(service).getUsers("111,222")
    // Then the correct set of users is returned
    assertEquals(Result.Success(users), result)
}
```

The way I see this exact test case is like:

```
@Test
fun getUsers_withSuccess() = runBlocking {
    val a = 4;
    assertEquals(a, 4)
}
```

How these two test cases are even different and how Plaid's case tests anything useful, I mean what bug can be caught with that test case? Is there a big picture in this test case that I'm missing out on?

**Note:** The way I see the `whenever {something} return` pattern is it was meant to be used in very rare cases but is being abused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it's the `getUsers` method of `dataSource` is tested, not the `getUsers` method of `service`.

It's supposed that `dataSource.getUsers` method have side effect - it calls `service.getUsers` under the hood.

This test checks 4 things:

1. call to `service.getUsers` actually happens when we call `dataSource.getUsers`
2. it happens only once
3. `dataSource.getUsers` correctly transforms its input parameter into input parameter for `service.getUsers` (`listOf(111L, 222L)` into `"111,222"`)
4. value returned from this internal call is not thrown away, but correctly used to produce overall return value (in this case it just returned as is)

Comment: Yeah, the point is that this is a *unit test* that is only dealing with the behaviour of a single component, in this case ``dataSource``. That component has a dependency, the ``service``, but you don't actually want to involve a real one of those, because now your test relies on the behaviour of two things (or more, depending on what ``service`` interacts with). So instead the test is mocking a ``service`` object, defining the specific things it should do during this test, and then checking all the interactions were what's expected. It's just an actor playing a role, if you like